# Dependent Formik Input Fields in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, formik

I am using Formik 2.2.9. I have two TextInput Fields that are dependent on each other, if I change one, the other should change as well.

```jsx
<Formik
    validationSchema={validationSchema}
    initialValues={{
        amount: "",
        exchangeAmount: "",
    }}
    onSubmit={(values) => handleSubmit(values)}
>
    {({
        handleChange,
        handleBlur,
        handleSubmit,
        setFieldValue,
        values,
        errors,
        touched,
    }) => (
            <ScrollView>
                <TextInput
                    placeholder="Amount"
                    keyboardType="number-pad"
                    value={values.amount}
                    onChangeText={(val) => {
                        const newVal= val / rate;
                        setFieldValue("amount", val);
                        setFieldValue("exchangeAmount", newVal);
                    }}
                />

                <TextInput
                    placeholder="Exchange Amount"
                    keyboardType="number-pad"
                    value={values.exchangeAmount}
                    onChangeText={(val) => {
                        const newVal= val * rate;
                        setFieldValue("exchangeAmount", val);
                        setFieldValue("amount", newVal);
                    }}
                />
            </ScrollView>
    )}
</Formik>
```

When I console the values in `onChnageText`, the value is updated but the changes don't render on the UI (TextField).

Comment: could you please provide more information ?

Comment: @AliSattarzadeh I think it's self explanatory

Comment: your code seems to be ok, so we need to see other parts to find the bug

Comment: where is rate defined ?

Comment: @AliSattarzadeh coming from API

Comment: @AliSattarzadeh Solved!

Answer (score 0):

```jsx
<Formik
    validationSchema={validationSchema}
    initialValues={{
        amount: "",
        exchangeAmount: "",
    }}
    onSubmit={(values) => handleSubmit(values)}
>
    {({
        handleChange,
        handleBlur,
        handleSubmit,
        values,
        errors,
        touched,
    }) => (
            <ScrollView>
                <TextInput
                    placeholder="Amount"
                    keyboardType="number-pad"
                    value={values.amount}
                    onChangeText={(val) => {
                        const newVal= val / rate;
                        handleChange("amount")(val);
                        handleChange("exchangeAmount")(
                            newVal.toString()
                        );
                    }}
                />

                <TextInput
                    placeholder="Exchange Amount"
                    keyboardType="number-pad"
                    value={values.exchangeAmount}
                    onChangeText={(val) => {
                        const newVal= val * rate;
                        handleChange("exchangeAmount")(val);
                        handleChange("amount")(
                            newVal.toString()
                        );
                    }}
                />
            </ScrollView>
    )}
</Formik>
```